# Add alternative text for an image in tagged pdf (PDF/UA) using iText

Tags: pdf, itext, accessibility

I've looked up some documentations and examples under the http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples.

I know iText is able to generate tagged pdf from scratch, but is it possible to insert alternative text to images in an existing **tagged** pdf (without changing anything else)? I need to implement this feature in a program without using GUI applications (such as Adobe Acrobat Pro). Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations, your question was selected for the [http://developers.itextpdf.com](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-alternative-text-image-tagged-pdf) web site!

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the [AddAltTags](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/archiving-and-accessibility/tagged-pdf-adding-alt-structure-tree#1553-addalttags.java) example.

In this example, we take a PDF with images of a fox and a dog where the Alt keys are missing: [no_alt_attribute.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/blob/master/resources/pdfs/no_alt_attribute.pdf)

[image]

Code can't recognize a fox or a dog, so we create a new document with Alt attributes saying "Figure without an Alt description": [added_alt_attributes.pdf)](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/pdfa/cmp_added_alt_attributes.pdf)

[image]

We add this description by walking through the structure tree, looking for structural elements marked as `/Figure` elements:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary catalog = reader.getCatalog();
    PdfDictionary structTreeRoot =
        catalog.getAsDict(PdfName.STRUCTTREEROOT);
    manipulate(structTreeRoot);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(
        reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
}

public void manipulate(PdfDictionary element) {
    if (element == null)
        return;
    if (PdfName.FIGURE.equals(element.get(PdfName.S))) {
        element.put(PdfName.ALT,
            new PdfString("Figure without an Alt description"));
    }
    PdfArray kids = element.getAsArray(PdfName.K);
    if (kids == null) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < kids.size(); i++)
        manipulate(kids.getAsDict(i));
}
```

You can easily port this Java example to C#:

- Get the root dictionary from the `PdfReader` object,
- Get the root of the structure tree (a dictionary),
- Loop over all the kids of every branch of that tree,
- When a lead is a figure, add an `/Alt` entry.

Once this is done, use `PdfStamper` to save the altered file.

Comment: Thanks! The example perfectly solves my question. Actually I have another additional question related: is it possible to know which picture it is from the information inside the marked content?

Comment: I am going to give you the most annoying answer that exists: *It depends...* If you show me a PDF, I can tell you if the info is there and if so, where. However, I fear that the information you're looking for is simply missing. If the information existed, it would have been added as an `/Alt` entry to the `/StructElem` dictionary. The fact that the `/Alt` entry is missing leaves to believe that the information you're looking for is nowhere to be found in the document.

Comment: I see, maybe the best solution is to assume that images appear the same order as the "figure" in the structure tree. Also, another question, is it possible to auto tag an untagged pdf using iText, or at least add a structure tree to an untagged pdf? Thanks

Comment: If you want to *properly* tag a PDF document, you always need a human being to make decisions that can't be made be a machine (or software).